# Doing an expression in Pandas instead of NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was actually doing this expression:

```py
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
np.array(w[0] + w[1]*np.array(X[:,0]) + w[2]*np.array(X[:,1]))
```

Now I have a Pandas dataframe and I wanna do it the same way but without converting it into a NumPy array, so what is the equivalent of this expression:

```
np.array(w[0] + w[1]*np.array(X[:,0]) + w[2]*np.array(X[:,1]))
```

in Pandas?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you maybe show us a picture of the DataFrame you might be playing with? I think I have a rough idea of what you are asking but it is abit confusing and uncertain without context of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.  Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: What's `w` and `X`.  I suspect all those `np.array(...)` wrappers aren't needed.

Comment: If `df` is your dataframe, why not: `w[0] + w[1] * df.iloc[:, 0] + w[2] * df.iloc[:, 1]`?